# Svg morph with anime js not changing path

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, anime.js

i'm trying to make some svg animations using anime js, i thought it would work just fine because, because i just need to change de `d` atribute.

I was using some blobs, but it seems that the code isn't recognizing their paths.
This is a pen i created to load the `svg's`
https://codepen.io/obarrier/pen/eYmyEEa

This is the pen of the animations 
https://codepen.io/obarrier/pen/NWPXvRy

I know i'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out where the error is...Because the path isn't being recognized

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should try to use paths with the same number of points and the same commands

Comment: I changed them again so that all of them had 10 points, but the paths might be diferent again i don't know why

Comment: they all have 10 points...but the animation is all messed up

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues. The first, is you have a space after .blobPath in your second codepen.

```
targets: '.blobPath ',
```

Secondly, your paths are really messed up. The 3 values you provide after the first value is waaaayyyyyy outside the view box. Plus it looks like you have a rotation on your main path, but you don't on your other paths.

[image: Showing path outside of view box]

I found that if you create one file for your animation. You can just duplicate a path and then rework the new path. Do this for each path you want to animate. That way you will be sure that the points are correct.

[image: Screenshot showing how to set up animation in layers]

Then you just export the SVG and open it up in your favorite text editor and copy the "d" values into your code.

```
d="M265.42,72.182l0,-72.182l-265.42,0l0,82.817c0,0 12.811,13.647 32.105,14.751c19.294,1.104 57.317,-11.093 57.317,-11.093l43.249,-13.139c0,0 20.977,-7.784 40.873,-7.784c19.897,0 38.711,7.784 38.711,7.784c0,0 27.756,11.399 41.335,7.557c13.579,-3.842 11.83,-8.711 11.83,-8.711Z"
```

I reworked your code pen, I think it's doing what you want it to do. I didn't spend a lot of time working on the paths. I'll leave that up to you.

https://codepen.io/cjboco/pen/zYGMmKm

Comment: I'm checking the pen, gonna work on the path, thanks !

Comment: I had mostly troubles, while making the transitions, because the svg didn't have the same number of points on both.